# Foreach inside a TikZ matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, foreach

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes] {
a \\
b \\
c \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It might be convenient to fill the matrix with a foreach loop:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes] {
\foreach \c in {a,b,c}{
\c \\
}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This however fails with the message

```
 ! Extra }, or forgotten
 \endgroup.
```

It seems like the ending brace of `\foreach` bothers the `matrix` node. Can a matrix be populated with `\foreach` and how?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`\foreach` isn't expandable and the grouping is most likely causing some issues as well. I would recommend to use the loop outside the matrix and accumulate the rows in a macro which then only has to be expanded. The `etoolbox` package provides `\gappto` (global append to; `\xappto` would cause issues with fragile content) which can be used here. There is also `\g@addto@macro` provided by the LaTeX kernel, if you don't want to rely on e-TeX and don't mind to have to use `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \let\mymatrixcontent\empty
    \foreach \c in {a,b,c}{%
        \expandafter\gappto\expandafter\mymatrixcontent\expandafter{\c\\}%
        % or
        %\xappto\mymatrixcontent{\expandonce{\c\\}}
    }
    \matrix [matrix of nodes] {
        \mymatrixcontent
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This code does not work with multiple columns, unfortunately. Adding a & causes a lot of compilation errors.

Comment: @gigabytes: Feel free to post a (separate) follow-up question ("Ask Question" above) with our code (best a minimal working example) you have so far. Please reference this answer there then. The table or matrix handling is quite special in (La)TeX and errors are common when special characters like `&` are placed in wrong or strange ways.

Comment: Rows and columns: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/596372/46023