# Nested foreach inside a TikZ matrix for both rows and columns

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to create a matrix using nested `\foreach` loops. I tried following the example  I found in a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22276/5109), but I keep getting errors.

Here is the code I tried to run:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\let\mymatrixcontent\empty
\newcommand{\row}[1]{
  \foreach \i in {0,...,5} {
    \xappto\mymatrixcontent{\expandonce{
      \node {\i}; & 
    }}
  }
  \xappto\mymatrixcontent{\\}
}
\row{1}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[matrix of nodes]{
    \mymatrixcontent
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm getting an error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\\  ->\let \reserved@e 
                       \relax \let \reserved@f \relax \@ifstar {\let \reserv...
l.16 \row{1}
```

I noticed that this error occurs only after adding the new row after the `\foreach` loop. Is there a way to avoid it?

**EDIT**: I completed the example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you do

```
\let\mymatrixcontent\empty
\newcommand{\row}{%
  \foreach \i in {0,...,5} {%
    \gappto\mymatrixcontent{\node{\i}; \&}%
    }%
  \gappto\mymatrixcontent{\\}%
}
\row
```

(using `\&` is better because of problems with "naked" `&` tokens; percusse's answer tells how to cope with this when building the matrix) then `\mymatrixcontent` will expand to

```
\node{\i}; \& \node{\i}; \& \node{\i}; \& \node{\i}; \& \node{\i}; \&\
```

and the current definition of `\i` will be used, which is "print a dotless i", because `\i` will expand to the successive values only during the action of `\foreach`. So what's needed is the expansion of `\i` during the action of `\foreach`:

```
\let\mymatrixcontent\empty
\newcommand{\row}{%
  \foreach \i in {0,...,5} {%
    \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
       \noexpand\gappto\noexpand\mymatrixcontent{\noexpand\node{\i}; \&}}\x
    }%
  \gappto\mymatrixcontent{\\}%
}
\row
```

However one has to pay close attention when using `\edef`: not all tokens are allowed inside the replacement text and those which we want to get as themselves need to be prefixed by `\noexpand`. In this particular case, where `\i` is the only token to be expanded, a different method can be used

```
\let\mymatrixcontent\empty
\newcommand{\row}{%
  \foreach \i in {0,...,5} {%
    \expandafter\gappto\expandafter\mymatrixcontent\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\node\expandafter{\i} \&}}%
    }%
  \gappto\mymatrixcontent{\\}%
}
\row
```

because the `\expandafter` chain will cause the expansion of `\i` before `\gappto` is executed.

---

A different approach could be with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\row}{mmm}
 {%#1 is the macro to define, #2 is the final number, #3 is the code
  \tl_clear_new:N #1
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 0 } { 1 } { #2 }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn #1 { #3 }
   }
  \tl_put_right:Nn #1 { \\ }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\row{\mymatrixcontent}{5}{\node { #1 }; \& }

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&]{
    \mymatrixcontent
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the third argument to `\row`, `#1` is successively evaluated as 0,...,5 (because 5 is the second argument).

[image]

Comment: I wasn't able to compile your first solution. I got `Too many }'s`.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but there's still an extra brace in the first solution (the second code segment). I would have deleted it myself, but SO doesn't allow me to do a single character edit.

Comment: Also, you should mention that if I want to use `\node` inside the `\edef`, I'll need to put `\noexpand` there as well.

Comment: @haggai_e Without seeing the "real" code, it's difficult to know what you want to append at every cycle.

Comment: After Altermundus' comment yesterday, I added an complete example of what I wanted to the question. It didn't include `\i` initially, but it did have a `\node` in each column. (I updated it now to include `\i` as well).

Comment: Is there any way to do this without polluting the global macro space with \gappto? I'd would be great if I could put the whole command including building the matrix inside braces and have nothing leak to a global context.  If not is there any general advice about what kind of name one should use when so polluting?

Comment: @PeterGerdes Use the second approach

Comment: @egreg Do you mean the expl3 approach?  I wasn't sure if that was being defined globally too or not because I’m still working of my latex3 knowledge.  Thanks.

Comment: @PeterGerdes If you place `\row` inside the `tikzpicture`, then `\mymatrixcontent` would be local to it.

Comment: @egreg I presume you mean in the expl3 version as otherwise \gappto presumably redefines it to be global during the execution of \row correct?  Sorry I just want to be sure I’m not misunderstanding you.  And thanks!

Comment: @PeterGerdes Yes, the `expl3` version; the `\foreach` based versions need global assignments.

Comment: By the way, this will create a seventh column (i.e. adding another `column sep` to the right and/or a node when `nodes in empty cells` is true).

Answer (score 6):

As Martin wrote in the linked answer it's working with `\gappto` command. Here is an example that works for me. I also changed the ampersand since it's always problematic to put a lonely `&` into the bowels of expanding macros :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\let\mymatrixcontent\empty
\newcommand{\row}[1]{
  \foreach \i in {0,...,5} {
    \gappto\mymatrixcontent{\expandonce{
     A  \& 
    }}
  }
  \gappto\mymatrixcontent{\\}
}
\row{1}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (a) [matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&]{
    \mymatrixcontent
  };
    \draw (a-1-1) -- (a-1-5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: code output]

Comment: Thanks! I had an error when I used `\gappto` at first, but I guess it was unrelated.

Comment: There's still a problem with this method. For some reason if I put `\i` after the `A`, the result is `A 1` in all the cells.

Comment: @haggai_e Hmm, that's not `1` but iota, dotless `i` character. Apparently, `\i` becomes a command rather than the argument of `foreach` loop. I'll try to fix it.

Comment: By the way, this will create a seventh column (i.e. adding another `column sep` to the right and/or a node when `nodes in empty cells` is true).

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\let\mymatrixcontent\empty
\foreach \row in {1,...,8}{%%
\foreach \col in {1,...,5}{%
\xappto\mymatrixcontent{r\row c\col \expandonce{\&}}
}%
\gappto\mymatrixcontent{\\}
}%%

\matrix[matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement=\&,
column sep=2ex,  label={Matrix}
] (m){
\mymatrixcontent 
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: By the way, this will create a sixth column (i.e. adding another `column sep` to the right and/or a node when `nodes in empty cells` is true).

Answer (score 1):

No expansion, no global assignments, no extra packages, no extra column, no ampersand shortcut, just two `\foreach` loops.

However, the `|…|` syntax of the `matrix` library can't be included anymore.
But when you generate the cells you can just use `\node[…]{…};` directly (or use the various `row …`/`column …`/`row … column …` styles to change the style of rows, columns or cells.

In your case, just use `create matrix={1}{1, ..., 5}` and `set matrix macro=#2`. Which will create `1` row with five columns `1`, `2`, …, `5` but just putting the column numbers in the nodes.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  % \protected because \pgfmatrixnextcell and \pgfmatrixendrow expand
  % → can't use |…| shortcut, though
  matrix node/.style 2 args={
    name=\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn,
    alias={\tikzmatrixname'-#1-#2}},
  set matrix macro/.code=
    \protected\def\tikzmatrixcell##1##2{\node[matrix node={##1}{##2}]{#1};},
  set matrix macro'/.code=\protected\def\tikzmatrixcell##1##2{#1},
  set matrix macro=r#1\,c#2,
  create matrix/.style 2 args={
    /tikz/matrix/content/.initial=,
    /tikz/matrix/create rows/.style={
      /tikz/matrix/reset create cell,
      /tikz/matrix/create columns/.style={
        /tikz/matrix/create cell={##1}{####1}},
      /tikz/matrix/create columns/.list={#2},
      /tikz/matrix/content/.append=\pgfmatrixendrow},
    /tikz/matrix/create rows/.list={#1},
    /tikz/node contents=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix/content}},
  matrix/reset create cell/.style={
    /tikz/matrix/create cell/.style 2 args={
      /tikz/matrix/content/.append=\tikzmatrixcell{##1}{##2},
      /tikz/matrix/create cell/.style 2 args={
        /tikz/matrix/content/.append=
          \pgfmatrixnextcell\tikzmatrixcell{####1}{####2}}}}}
\begin{document}
\tikz
\matrix[
  draw, column sep=2ex,
  set matrix macro=#2, create matrix={1}{1, ..., 5}];

\tikz
\matrix (m) [
  draw, column sep=2ex, row sep=1em,
  row 1 column 1/.style={set matrix macro=},
  column 1/.append style={set matrix macro=row    ##1},
  row    1/.append style={set matrix macro=column ##2},
  set matrix macro=#2#1, % like a spreadsheet
  create matrix={0, ..., 8}{0, A, B, ..., E}]
  (m'-1-A) edge[out=0, in=180] (m'-4-B);
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]