# Using foreach loop variable as node label in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, foreach

I have a (multi)line plot generated from a table in pgfplots:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\pgfplotstableread{table.tsv}\loadedtable
  \foreach \metavar in {foo,bar} {
    \addplot table[x index=1,y=\metavar] from \loadedtable node {\metavar};
  }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This works well **except** for the node I want to place at the end of each line as a kind of *inline* legend.

Here, LaTeX complains:

```
! Argument of \T1\metavar has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                 \par
```

If I substitute the `\metavar` node label with some literal text, everything compiles fine, but this of course misses the point of the `\foreach`. So how do I access a loop variable in a place like this?

Comment: Feels like a duplicate of [this one here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47649/3235) but I'm not sure

Comment: Related Question [PGFplots foreach equivalent to TikZ's with multiple variables separated by a slash](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17638/pgfplots-foreach-equivalent-to-tikzs-with-multiple-variables-separated-by-a-sla/17817#17817) which has a good explanation of the issue here.

Comment: @Andreas: When posting code examples like yours, it's usually a good idea to make them complete and compilable (i.e. include `\documentclass` and all packages that are necessary), and self-sufficient (in this case, that would mean including dummy data). That saves people who try to help the effort of having to complete the code themselves first.

Comment: @Jake: Sorry. Will post complete examples from now on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, you'll have to use the `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped`, which makes sure that the loop is not executed inside its own group.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\pgfplotstableread[row sep=crcr]{
X foo bar\\
1 10 20\\
2 10 30\\
3 20 40\\
}\loadedtable
  \pgfplotsinvokeforeach {foo,bar} {
    \addplot table [x index=0,y=#1] \loadedtable node [anchor=south] {#1};
  }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me (using the pgfplots that shipped with TeX Live 2011); both lines are labelled "bar". (Also, using `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` exhibits this behaviour.)

Comment: @Andreas: Sorry, you're right, `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` didn't fix the problem. For me, `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` does, however. Can you try with the edited code in my answer?

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. Thanks for you help.