# Generic point labels in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have loads of `pgfplot`s which have one thing in common, they all containt one or two `addplot` with four points that I want to label with the same labels, namely: `\tau_c= n \theta`. Lets for simplicity say `n` is `1`, `2`,`3` and `4`. [Using foreach loop variable as node label in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50477/using-foreach-loop-variable-as-node-label-in-pgfplots) looks very much like something that could solve my problem. But how do I append this (or similar) solution when the coordinates are given as in the MWE below? My `pgfplot`s are generated with `matlab2tikz` and are as mentioned quite numerous, so I would like to avoid having to manipulate the existing file too much.

An MWE

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% [spy using outlines={rectangle,black,magnification=3,connect spies}]
\begin{axis}[%
width=3in,
height=1in,
unbounded coords=jump,
scale only axis,
xmin=1.25,
xmax=3,
xlabel={That},
ymin=0,
ymax=8,
ylabel={This},
title={Case 11},
% legend style={draw=black,fill=white,legend cell align=left}
]
\addplot [
color=red,
only marks,
mark=o,
mark options={solid},
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
2.17534491233797 1.76417509678952\\
1.70352168717505 2.47466020520172\\
1.50385056450878 3.36056987643388\\
1.39330071637349 4.41283273476325\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `nodes near coords` function for that. If you add

```
\pgfplotsset{
    nodes near coords={
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\nValue{\coordindex+1}%
        $\nValue \theta$%
    }
}
```

to your document, the node labels will be printed without you having to touch the `matlab2tikz`-generated code at all:

[image]

---

If you want to be able to provide arbitrary labels that don't directly depend on the coordinate index, you can use a PGF math array that stores the strings for the labels and access that array within the `nodes near coords`:

```
\def\labellist{{"$\sfrac{1}{2}\theta$","$\theta$","$\sfrac{3}{2}\theta$","$2\theta$"}}
\pgfplotsset{
    nodes near coords={
        \pgfmathparse{\labellist[\coordindex]}%
        \pgfmathresult
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Amen! Is it possible to somehow make the `nodes near coords` append to only one or two of many `addplot`s in the same `axis` environment? Somehow label the `addplot`, maybe?

Comment: @Holene: You can just put the `nodes near coords={...}` in the `\addplot[...]` options for the relevant plot.

Comment: Oh, sorry for the quick return; what if I would have `n` to be a macro? For instance `\sfrac{1}{2}`...

Comment: @Holene: Would the values in the `\sfrac` depend on the coordinate index in some way? Or would you rather hard code them by providing a list of labels?

Comment: Dependency in coordinate index is not necessary, just to pick the following values for each label would suffice: `$\sfrac{1}{2}\theta$`, `$\theta$`, `$\sfrac{3}{2}\theta$`, `$2\theta$`...

Comment: May I upvote twice, please?