# Index variable appears to escape the \foreach loop and then wrecks stuff

Tags: foreach, pgffor

I'm using `pgfplotstable` to create standalone graphs of test data. I've included `pgffor` and I'm trying to use a `\foreach` loop to iterate over the three output channels for a given unit under test within a single `groupplot`. Lucky for me, I'm getting compilation errors that refer to the index variable (called `\chan`), and which point to lines *outside* the loop, where `\chan` isn't used.

Here's a stripped-down version of my file that's causing trouble:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}


\newcommand{\voltticks}{-10,0,...,30}
\newcommand{\voltmin}{-18}
\newcommand{\voltmax}{35}
\newcommand{\currmin}{-0.5}
\newcommand{\currmax}{8}

% Different color for each channel on each unit
\newcommand{\uutchan}[2]{%
    \ifcase #1 error% There's no uut #0
        \or \ifcase #2 colorerror% nor any channel #0
            \or black%
            \or brown%
            \or red%
        \fi%
        \or \ifcase #2 colorerror%
            \or orange%
            \or yellow%
            \or green%
        \fi%
        \or \ifcase #2 colorerror%
            \or blue%
            \or purple%
            \or grey%
        \fi%
    \fi}

\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
            xmin=0,
            xmax=5,
            xtick={1,2,...,5},
            }}

\newcommand{\uut}{1}

% All the data files have the same filename structure
\newcommand{\lvdata}[1]{plot-data/lv-data-uut-\uut-ch-#1.csv}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
    \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={
            group size=1 by 2,
        },
        no markers,
        width=6in,
    ]
        \nextgroupplot[
            ymin=\voltmin,
            ymax=\voltmax,
            ytick=\voltticks,
            ylabel={Voltage (\si{\volt})},
            xticklabels=\empty,
            title={Boy, I wish this would work right},
            height=1.75in,
        ]
            \foreach \chan in {1,2,3}{%
                \addplot[\uutchan{\uut}{\chan}] table [%
                    col sep=comma,%
                    x={elapsed_time},%
                    y={voltage},%
                ] {\lvdata{\chan}};%
                \addlegendentry{Channel \chan}%
            }                                   % <<-- end of the \foreach loop


        \nextgroupplot[
            ymin=\currmin,
            ymax=\currmax,
            xlabel={Elapsed Time},
            ylabel={Current (\si{\ampere})},
            height=1.75in,
        ]                                       % <<-- here's line 79
            \addplot[\uutchan{\uut}{1}] table [
                col sep=comma,
                x={elapsed_time},
                y={current},
            ] {\lvdata{1}};
            \addlegendentry{Channel 1}
            \addplot[\uutchan{\uut}{2}] table [
                col sep=comma,
                x={elapsed_time},
                y={current},
            ] {\lvdata{2}};
            \addlegendentry{Channel 2}
            \addplot[\uutchan{\uut}{3}] table [
                col sep=comma,
                x={elapsed_time},
                y={current},
            ] {\lvdata{3}};
            \addlegendentry{Channel 3}

    \end{groupplot}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here's the error message I get:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translations/translations-basic-d
ictionary-english.trsl)
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \chan

l.79            ]
```

I don't understand why it looks like `\chan` is being called several lines after the end of the loop.

I know that run-on commands sometimes show up a little later in the file, but I've double-checked my brace count to make sure I didn't forget to close the code block, and it's correct.

Also worth noting is that if I *don't* use the `\foreach` loop, there are no problems. The way the second `groupplot` is written shows what that would look like.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Edit: Updated with a M(non-)WE instead of a code snippet.

---

Contents of plot-data/lv-data-uut-1-ch-1.csv:

```
elapsed_time,voltage,current
1,5.12088502740541,1.18375845641884
2,5.81177332147156,1.6640415277584
3,6.3936508576718,2.47855204713269
4,5.77677606311296,1.88676641772499
5,6.08716354605412,2.68562189308305
```

---

Contents of plot-data/lv-data-uut-1-ch-2.csv:

```
elapsed_time,voltage,current
1,14.7367967957342,3.58490117433496
2,14.2603519819053,3.15772195035904
3,15.219470298334,2.60505323186182
4,15.8054999682348,4.0885748772842
5,14.602837758358,3.92571012858714
```

---

Contents of plot-data/lv-data-uut-1-ch-3.csv:

```
elapsed_time,voltage,current
1,-4.68980292044475,6.07093702142046
2,-5.52369547515492,6.60095794734899
3,-3.14599831983585,6.49047991092652
4,-5.57765267954762,6.86674835669737
5,-4.3030082035212,5.32605451112347
```

Comment: The related links on the side of this page led me to [Using foreach loop variable as node label in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50477/using-foreach-loop-variable-as-node-label-in-pgfplots?rq=1), and the answer there worked for me. Replacing ```\foreach``` with ```\pgfplotsinvokeforeach``` made it work the way I expected. I don't know whether I should delete my question or answer it, or if it should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: close as dup is usually best (your question then stays but leads people to the other)