# Programmatically setting column style of a matrix in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

I'm trying to programmatically set the style of the columns of a TikZ matrix. My attempt is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzstyle{mymatrix}=[draw]  
\foreach \c [count=\i] in {red, green, blue} {
    \globaldefs=1        % make tikz style global
    \tikzset{mymatrix/.append style={column \i/.style={nodes={fill=\c}}}}
}

\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, mymatrix] {
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 5 & 6 & 8 & 8 \\ };

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this code does not compile because the commands `\i` and `\c` are undefined. My guess is that the style inside the for-loop has to be expanded inside the for-loop, but I don't know how to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can expand the variables by using an `\edef` to define a new command:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzstyle{mymatrix}=[draw]  
\foreach \c [count=\i] in {red, green, blue} {
    \globaldefs=1 
    \edef\dotikzset{
        \noexpand\tikzset{
            mymatrix/.append style={
                column \i/.style={
                    nodes={fill=\c}
                }
            }
        }
    }
    \dotikzset
}

\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, mymatrix] {
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 5 & 6 & 8 & 8 \\ };

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

Jake was faster but here is something I learned from egreg [in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47595/3235) :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\let\mystyle\empty
\newcommand{\populatestyle}{%
  \foreach \c [count=\i] in {red, green, blue} {
    \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
       \noexpand\gappto\noexpand\mystyle{column \i/.style={nodes={fill=\c}},}}\x
    }%
}
\populatestyle

\tikzset{mymatrix/.estyle={\mystyle}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,mymatrix] {
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\ };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting solution, I will keep this approach in mind, it might come in handy. Thanks!

Comment: Why does the `\endgroup` command have to be inside the definition of `\x`?

Comment: @Yori It's better to remove it anyway :) `\edef\x{\noexpand\gappto\noexpand\mystyle{column \i/.style={nodes={fill=\c}},}}\x` should work too.

Comment: Yes, I noticed; I just used your idea in a different part of my code. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather old question which has two excellent answers. Nevertheless, there might be some room for yet another answer which neither uses `\globaldefs` nor loads another package. (This answer has a weak point: if the list of colors has less entries than the matrix has rows, then there will be an error.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[colorize cells/.style={/utils/exec={%
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{{#1}[\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn-1]}
 \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/fill=\mycolor}}}]
 \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,nodes={colorize cells={"red","green","blue","white"}}] {
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 5 & 6 & 8 & 8 \\ };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]