# Programmatically styling tixz matrix nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I'm trying to write a macro that given some coordinates colors the corresponding cells in a matrix black. This is related to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55525/programmatically-setting-column-style-of-a-matrix-in-tikz). I fail at adapting one of the answers from that question. Here is some code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{mymatrix}=[draw]  
\foreach \i in {1,2,3} {
    \globaldefs=1 
    \edef\dotikzset{
        \noexpand\tikzset{
            mymatrix/.append style={
                row \i column \i/.style={
                    nodes={fill=black}
                }
            }
        }
    }
    \dotikzset
}

  \matrix [matrix of nodes, mymatrix, nodes in empty cells, nodes={draw, minimum size=5mm}]
  {
     &  &  \\
     &  &  \\
     &  &  \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I expect it to color the diagonal black, but it only produces white cells. If I replace one of the `\i` in the `row \i column \i` line with a constant, it works just fine. I don't understand why it doesn't work with two references to `\i`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When TeX expands `row \i column \i/.style` the space after the `\i` is removed. So when `\i` is `1` the result is `row 1column 1`.

One way around this is to use `\space` after the first `\i`: `row \i\space column \i/.style`

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the list handler

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mymatrix/.style={draw}]  
\tikzset{
  mymatrix/.append style={row #1 column #1/.style={nodes={fill=black}}},
  mymatrix/.list={1,2,3}
}
  \matrix [matrix of nodes, mymatrix, nodes in empty cells, nodes={draw, minimum size=5mm}]
  {
     &  &  \\
     &  &  \\
     &  &  \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```