# How to "demux" several aspects from a `\foreach` variable with `\ifstrequal`?

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, expansion, foreach

> How can I "demux" several features from a mode specification given in a `\foreach`?

I would like to use a `\foreach` to draw several nodes in a TikZ picture.  The loop will specify a mode for each node, and, in turn, the mode will be used to set several features of the style and position of the node.  Since the mode specifies a group of features, I want to "demux" those features from the mode specification, rather than having to list each feature in the `\foreach`.  A minimal not-working example is

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \mode/\loc in {small/{(0,0)}, large/{(2,0)}}
  {
    \edef\myscale{\ifstrequal{\mode}{large}{1}{0.25}}
    \edef\mycolor{\ifstrequal{\mode}{large}{black}{gray}}

    \typeout{\meaning\myscale}
    \typeout{\meaning\mycolor}
    \node [scale=\myscale, color=\mycolor, draw] at \loc {\myscale\mycolor};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I try to compile this, I get the error `! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color \ifstrequal{small}{large}{black}{gray}.`

It seems that the conditional needs to be expanded before being passed to the style, but I do not know how to do this.  Surprisingly (at least to me), if I remove `scale=\myscale, color=\mycolor` from the style, then I get the following output.

[image]

So, for some reason, the node text expands the conditional, but the style does not.

(*Aside question:* Why do my images in posts always turn out so small?)

**Edit:** It appears that the `\foreach` is somewhat of a red herring for the above error message.  Specifically, the following simpler code produces the same error:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\def\mode{small}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [scale=\ifstrequal{\mode}{large}{1}{0.25}, draw]
        {\ifstrequal{\mode}{large}{1}{0.25}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Although @percusse's answer is best for my particular use, I'm still interested to know why this error occurs.  Also, is it possible to force expansion of `\ifstrequal`?

Comment: Your image is small to begin with. I have replaced it.

Comment: @PeterGrill How should I make the image bigger to begin with?  What  I did was to compile the code and upload the resulting pdf.  I guess what I'm asking is what workflow you used for the above image.

Comment: I upload a PNG from a screen capture on a mac, and zoom in on the image until it is of a reasonable size prior to the capturing the image.

Comment: @PeterGrill @HenryDeYoung The `standalone` class provides a useful option: `convert`.

Comment: Not to address your question at all, but why can't you just use a `pgfkeys` style rather than your "mode"?  I mean, that's exactly how it turns out.

Comment: @RyanReich If you mean something like what percusse suggested, yes, that is what I'm going to do now.  The reason that I factor out the style name, though, is that I'll eventually replace it with `#1` etc. so that I can give just a short name rather than a full style when I call the command that uses the `\foreach`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Expanding in the foreach list is often problematic and needs to be performed just at the right spot. Few examples are

[Nested foreach inside a TikZ matrix for both rows and columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47595/nested-foreach-inside-a-tikz-matrix-for-both-rows-and-columns)

[Tikz foreach inside matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60394/tikz-foreach-inside-matrix)

The style definition keys are recommended also to avoid such problems.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{l/.style={scale=1,black},s/.style={scale=0.25,gray}}
\foreach \mode/\loc in {s/{(0,0)}, l/{(2,0)}}{
    \node [\mode] at \loc {\mode};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would also stay away from the literal words to define styles and variables since any other package can also define the same ones and it would lead to unnecessary debugging effort.

Comment: IMHO, It's a perfect solution: concise, effective and legible.

Comment: @percusse I agree with @PolGab; this is a nifty solution!

Answer (score 6):

Not sure what is going on with `\ifstrequal`, but you can use the `\IfStrEq` from  [the `xstring` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xstring/)

```
\IfStrEq{\mode}{large}{%
    \gdef\myscale{1}%
    \gdef\mycolor{black}%
}{%
    \gdef\myscale{0.25}%
    \gdef\mycolor{gray}%
}%
```

which produces:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \mode/\loc in {small/{(0,0)}, large/{(2,0)}}
  {
    \IfStrEq{\mode}{large}{%
        \gdef\myscale{1}%
        \gdef\mycolor{black}%
    }{%
        \gdef\myscale{0.25}%
        \gdef\mycolor{gray}%
    }%

    \node [scale=\myscale, color=\mycolor, draw] at \loc {\myscale\mycolor};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

I would actually recommend you use `\tikzset` to define styles:

```
\IfStrEq{\mode}{large}{%
    \tikzset{MyStyle/.style={scale=1, color=black}}
}{%
    \tikzset{MyStyle/.style={scale=0.25, color=gray}}
}%
```

which produces identical results as above.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \mode/\loc in {small/{(0,0)}, large/{(2,0)}}
  {
    \IfStrEq{\mode}{large}{%
        \tikzset{MyStyle/.style={scale=1, color=black}}
    }{%
        \tikzset{MyStyle/.style={scale=0.25, color=gray}}
    }%

    \node [MyStyle, draw] at \loc {\myscale\mycolor};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this does not technically answer your question in terms of `\ifstrequal`, but provides a work-around. You can use a different - more primitive - approach to conditioning via `\ifx...\else...\fi`:

```
\def\mystring{large}%
\ifx\mode\mystring
  \def\myscale{1}%
  \def\mycolor{black}%
\else% \mode is not large
  \def\myscale{0.25}%
  \def\mycolor{gray}%
\fi%
```

[image]