# Setting the color of a draw command inside foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I am trying to draw colored lines with a foreach loop. The command I use to draw the line creates a colored line if I use it standalone. Once I put it inside the foreach loop, I only get a black line. How do I draw colored lines inside a foreach loop?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[lengthMark/.style={<->}]
    \foreach \i/\color in {0/{violet!50},1/yellow} {
        \draw[\color] (3.5, -.25-\i) -- ++(.5, 0);
        \draw[red] (0,0) --(2,2);
    }
\draw[red] (0,0) --(2,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[write latex](https://www.writelatex.com/335559vmtwny), note while posting it only the line drawn outside the foreach (`\draw[red] (0,0) --(2,-2);`) appears colored.

Comment: `\color` is an important macro for `xcolor`. And inside `\foreach` you overwrite it.  I've changed it to `\mycolor` in writelatex. Can you confirm if that is what you want?

Comment: @percusse: confirmed, I already accepted gonzolas awnser

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a different name instead of `\color`; in general, I always try to avoid using names which correspond to already defined commands:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i/\colora in {0/{violet!50},1/yellow} {
        \draw[\colora] (3.5, -.25-\i) -- ++(.5, 0);
        \draw[red] (0,0) --(2,2);
    }
\draw[red] (0,0) --(2,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, also `\i` is defined. But if no strange text is involved, it shouldn't be a problem like using `\color`.

Comment: @egreg http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47595/nested-foreach-inside-a-tikz-matrix-for-both-rows-and-columns :P

Comment: @egreg:that is good to know. But as I just saw per percusses link, you have the same habit of using i as a loop index ;). Is there a way to test if a name is free?

Comment: @ted If iota is not required then you can use it in the loop via overwriting it but `\color` is essential to TikZ.

Comment: @percusse: the essential part I learned the hard way, thus my comment if there is a way to check if i overwrite something (I believe e.g. `newcommand` disallows overwriting for this reason), and since I am no latex guru (I had no need to use `\color` yet) I overlook these things...

Comment: @percusse Oh, yes! But that's a slightly different problem.