# Tikz-matrix by loop, calculations inside

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, foreach, loops

I looked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47595/nested-foreach-inside-a-tikz-matrix-for-both-rows-and-columns) and tried to use 
`\expandonce{\pgfmathprint{\n+1}}  \expandonce{\&} Text`
inside the matrixcontent-loop.

But this does not work. What do I have to do?

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={   f(\n)=0.5*\n;     },
]
\let\mymatrixcontent\empty
\foreach \n in {1,...,8}{%%
\xappto\mymatrixcontent{
%\expandonce{\pgfmathprint{f(\n)}}  \expandonce{\&} works not
%\expandonce{\pgfmathprint{\n+1}}  \expandonce{\&} works not too
\expandonce{\pgfmathprint{1+1}}  \expandonce{\&} works
}
\gappto\mymatrixcontent{\\}
}%%

\matrix[matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement=\&](m){
\mymatrixcontent 
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to expand just `\n`, so something like

```
\xappto\mymatrixcontent{%
  \noexpand\pgfmathprint{\n} \noexpand\&
  \noexpand\pgfmathprint{f(\n)} \noexpand\&
  \noexpand\pgfmathprint{\n+1} \noexpand\\
}
```

Under standard settings `\noexpand\&` might be just `\&`, but `\noexpand` doesn't hurt and would be necessary if `\&` somehow gets a different definition.

You can do it in different ways.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\intstep}{O{1}mm}
 {
  \int_step_inline:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

% emulation of etoolbox \appto
\ProvideDocumentCommand{\appto}{mm}
 {
  \tl_put_right:Nn #1 { #2 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\n)=0.5*\n;}]
  \def\mymatrixcontent{}
  \intstep{8}{
    \appto\mymatrixcontent{\pgfmathprint{#1} \& \pgfmathprint{f(#1)} \& \pgfmathprint{#1+1} \\}
  }
  \matrix[matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement=\&](m){
    \mymatrixcontent
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

$\tikzset{declare function={f(\n)=0.5*\n;}}
\begin{array}{ccc}
  \intstep{8}{\pgfmathprint{#1} & \pgfmathprint{f(#1)} & \pgfmathprint{#1+1} \\}
\end{array}$

\end{document}
```

The `\intstep` command takes as optional argument the starting point (default 1), then two mandatory arguments, namely the upper bound and a template for what to do, where the current index is denoted by `#1`.

For the Ti*k*Z matrix, the indirection of first populating a scratch token list variable seems needed. Not so for a simpler `array` approach.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The `\expandonce` macro only expands what's directly in front of it, here `\pgfmathprint`, and only once at that. It will certainly not expand `\n` which is what you want here. I'd suggest

```
\xappto\mymatrixcontent{\noexpand\pgfmathprint{f(\n)}}
\gappto\mymatrixcontent{\&\\}
```

protecting `\pgfmathprint` from expansion. There's no need to expand `\&`, this is only defined properly inside `\matrix`. Or even

```
\gappto\mymatrixcontent{\pgfmathprint}
\xappto\mymatrixcontent{{f(\n)}}% double braces!
\gappto\mymatrixcontent{\&\\}
```

Or just

```
\xappto\mymatrixcontent{%
  \noexpand\pgfmathprint{f(\n)}\noexpand\&\noexpand\\}%
```

I'll also provide two different approaches

1. by using an ungrouped loop via the `.list` handler and PGFkeys own “appto” (in the form of the `.append` key handler) and
2. by using `matrix`' own row counter `\pgfmatrixcurrentrow` which we can use inside PGFMath.

The first alternative solution uses `\foreach` internally, so you can use any `\foreach` compatible list (like `{1,...,8,10,17,35.5}`). Since we use a style we can automatically set the matrix' content without having to specify it again.

The second alternative is probably not the easiest in this case but isn't that powerless either. Though, for more complex tables, the [pgfplotstable](/questions/tagged/pgfplotstable) package might be worth to invest in.

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}

% 0. using \foreach and etoolbox
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\n)=0.5*\n;}]
\def\mymatrixcontent{$x$\&$f(x)$\\}
\foreach \n in {1,...,8}{
  \xappto\mymatrixcontent{
    \noexpand\pgfmathprint{\n}
    \noexpand\&
    \noexpand\pgfmathprint{f(\n)}\noexpand\\}}
\matrix[matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement=\&] (m) {\mymatrixcontent};
\end{tikzpicture}

% 1. using .list and PGFkeys (w/o etoolbox)
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\n)=0.5*\n;},
  row builder/.style={
    /mymatrixcontent/.initial=$x$\&$f(x)$\\,
    @row builder/.list={#1},
    node contents=\pgfkeysvalueof{/mymatrixcontent}},
  @row builder/.style={
    /mymatrixcontent/.append=#1 \& \pgfmathprint{f(#1)} \\}]
\matrix (m) [
  matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement=\&,
  row builder={1,...,8}];
\end{tikzpicture}

% 2. using row counter
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\n)=0.5*\n;}]
\matrix[
  matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement=\&, nodes in empty cells,
  column 1/.append style={nodes={node contents=\pgfmathprint{int(\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-1)}}},
  column 2/.append style={nodes={node contents=\pgfmathprint{f(\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-1)}}},
  row 1 column 1/.style={nodes={node contents=$x$}},
  row 1 column 2/.style={nodes={node contents=$f(x)$}}
  ] (m) { \& \\ \& \\ \& \\ \& \\ \& \\ \& \\ \& \\ \& \\ \& \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]