# Generating matrices with a single command

Tags: expl3, tikz-matrix

Suppose I wanted to generate a 5x4 matrix. A good way to do it is to write the following commands:

```
    \[
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix(m) [matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement=\&, row sep=1ex, column sep=1ex, nodes in empty cells, nodes={shape=rectangle,minimum height=3ex, anchor=center},] {                                
            $A_{11}$  \& $A_{12}$ \& $A_{13}$ \& $A_{14}$  \\
            $A_{21}$  \& $A_{22}$ \& $A_{23}$ \& $A_{24}$  \\
            $A_{31}$  \& $A_{32}$ \& $A_{33}$ \& $A_{34}$  \\
            $A_{41}$  \& $A_{42}$ \& $A_{43}$ \& $A_{44}$  \\
            $A_{51}$  \& $A_{52}$ \& $A_{53}$ \& $A_{54}$  \\
        };
        \node[fit= (m-1-1.north west) (m-5-4.south east), left delimiter={[}, right delimiter={]},inner sep=1ex] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}            
    \]
```

(I use `tikz` because it allows me to format individual matrix elements and insert graphics).
This can get rather tiring if I have to populate a 10x9 matrix. The idea is to write a
NewDocumentCommand with three inputs: the letter denoting the matrix, the number of rows and the number of columns. Using `expl3` I should be able to generate the matrix contents. Then I should be able to write something like,

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix(m) [matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement=\&, row sep=1ex, column sep=1ex, nodes in empty cells, nodes={shape=rectangle,minimum height=3ex, anchor=center},] {    
           \matrixcontents                      
        };
        \node[fit= (m-1-1.north west) (m-#2-#3.south east), left delimiter={[}, right delimiter={]},inner sep=1ex] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

where `\matrixcontents` contains

```
            $A_{11}$  \& $A_{12}$ \& $A_{13}$ \& $A_{14}$  \\
            $A_{21}$  \& $A_{22}$ \& $A_{23}$ \& $A_{24}$  \\
            $A_{31}$  \& $A_{32}$ \& $A_{33}$ \& $A_{34}$  \\
            $A_{41}$  \& $A_{42}$ \& $A_{43}$ \& $A_{44}$  \\
            $A_{51}$  \& $A_{52}$ \& $A_{53}$ \& $A_{54}$  \\
```

and `#2`, `#3` are respectively the number of rows, number of columns arguments of
the NewDocumentCommand (in this example `#1` is the letter A).

I am an absolute beginner with `expl3` and so I have no idea how to generate `\matrixcontents`.

Comment: Related: [Q47595](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47595) and many more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\matrixcontents}{mmm}
 {% #1 = symbol, #2 = number of rows, #3 = number of columns
  \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
  \int_step_inline:nn { #2 }
   {% ##1 = row index
    \int_step_inline:nn { #3 - 1 }
     {% ####1 = column index
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { $#1\sb{##1####1}$ \& }
     }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { $#1\sb{##1#3}$ \\ }
   }
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix(m) [
    matrix of nodes,
     ampersand replacement=\&,
     row sep=1ex,
     column sep=1ex,
     nodes in empty cells,
     nodes={
       shape=rectangle,
       minimum height=3ex,
       anchor=center
     },
   ]{
      \matrixcontents{A}{5}{4}
   };
   \node[
     fit= (m-1-1.north west) (m-5-4.south east),
     left delimiter={[},
     right delimiter={]},
     inner sep=1ex
   ] {};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \]

\end{document}
```

The code performs a loop on the rows and in each one a loop on the columns (the last cell in a row is special).

[image]

Even shorter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit}

\NewDocumentCommand{\symbolicmatrix}{O{}mmm}{%
  % #1 = further options, #2 = symbol, #3 = number of rows, #4 = number of columns
  \matrix(m) [
    matrix of nodes,
     ampersand replacement=\&,
     row sep=1ex,
     column sep=1ex,
     nodes in empty cells,
     nodes={
       shape=rectangle,
       minimum height=3ex,
       anchor=center
     },#1,
   ]{\matrixcontents{#2}{#3}{#4}};
   \node[
     fit= (m-1-1.north west) (m-#3-#4.south east),
     left delimiter={[},
     right delimiter={]},
     inner sep=1ex
   ] {};
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\matrixcontents}{mmm}
 {% #1 = symbol, #2 = number of rows, #3 = number of columns
  \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
  \int_step_inline:nn { #2 }
   {% ##1 = row index
    \int_step_inline:nn { #3 - 1 }
     {% ####1 = column index
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { $#1\sb{##1####1}$ \& }
     }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { $#1\sb{##1#3}$ \\ }
   }
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \symbolicmatrix{A}{5}{4}
\end{tikzpicture}
\]

\end{document}
```

The `\symbolicmatrix` command has a leading optional argument for more options to the `\matrix` command.

For instance

```
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \symbolicmatrix[row sep=2ex,column sep=2ex]{A}{5}{4}
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
```

would produce

[image]

Comment: Genius! I did not realise it can be done just by using a token list!

Answer (score 3):

For information, the package `nicematrix` provides commands to generated matrices where each cell is in a TikZ node (it's not a `tikz-matrix`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

$\bAutoNiceMatrix[name=A]{5-4}{A_{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}}}$

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw [<-] (A-5-2) -- ++ (0,-5mm) node [below] {$x$} ; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thanks. `nice matrix` is a great package; the reason I use `tikz` for matrices is because it allows for nested matrices (i.e. matrices whose elements are matrices) through the use of commands like  `fit= (m-1-1.north west) (m-#3-#4.south east),left delimiter={[},right delimiter={]},inner sep=1ex ] {};` `tikz` also allows multiple headers for columns and rows; so for a nested matrix I could have a separate line for each index, however many indices I use for rows and columns.

Comment: I understand. However, you should have a look at the command `\Submatrix` of `nicematrix`.

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to @egreg's answer, but builds the matrix body with expandable code, the result should be faster code (but I didn't benchmark). Also the `tikzpicture` environment is included in the macro (you might remove it if you don't want this).

I hope the comments are enough to explain the code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, fit}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l__ted_matrix_cols_int
\tl_new:N \l__ted_matrix_variable_tl
\cs_new:Npn \__ted_matrix_row:n #1
  {
    % after we built a row we need to remove the leading \exp_not:N \& from the
    % first cell
    \exp_last_unbraced:Ne \use_none:nn
      {
        % \prg_replicate:nn needs two steps of expansion
        % we use it instead of an \int_map_... because there is no \int_map_...
        % that allows us to expandably forward additional arguments (#1)
        \exp_args:No \use_ii_i:on
          { \prg_replicate:nn \l__ted_matrix_cols_int \__ted_matrix_cell:nnN }
          { \__ted_matrix_cell:nnN 1 {#1} }
        % the \use_none:nn ends the \__ted_matrix_cell:nnN loop
        \use_none:nn
      }
    \exp_not:N \\
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \use_ii_i:nn { o }
% simple loop to return each cell
\cs_new:Npn \__ted_matrix_cell:nnN #1#2#3
  {
    % will be wrapped in two e-expansion contexts, inner one is from the row,
    % outer one is from building the entire body
    % $, #1, #2, and \sb don't need protection against further expansion.
    \exp_not:n { \exp_not:N \& $ \exp_not:V \l__ted_matrix_variable_tl \sb { #2#1 } $ }
    \exp_args:Ne #3 { \int_eval:n { #1 + 1 } } {#2}
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \tmatrix { O{} m m m }
  {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \tl_set:Nn \l__ted_matrix_variable_tl {#2}
      % we store #4-1 because one is hardcoded by the way we start the loop to
      % build each cell of a row.
      \int_set:Nn \l__ted_matrix_cols_int { #4 - 1 }
      \exp_args:Nne \use:n
        {
          \matrix(m) [matrix~of~nodes, ampersand~replacement=\&,
            row~sep=1ex, column~sep=1ex, nodes~in~empty~cells,
            nodes={shape=rectangle,minimum~height=3ex, anchor=center}, #1]
        }
        { \int_step_function:nN {#3} \__ted_matrix_row:n }
        ;
      \node[fit= (m-1-1.north~west) (m-#3-#4.south~east), left~delimiter={[},
        right~delimiter={]},inner~sep=1ex]
        {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\tmatrix{A}{5}{4}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I need to do some more reading to grasp code expansion. Your code is definitely fast I just need to make sure I understand what I am doing...

Comment: @TedBlack in practice the version by egreg should be fast enough (you'd have to produce loads of matrices to notice the difference, and even then, the real choke will most likely be the Ti*k*Z part, not the matrix body generation). This is more for educational purposes, imho.

Comment: Would be great if someone writes “expl3 expansion guide for idiots” Have been going through l3expan but still no light…

Comment: @TedBlack it's basically TeX expansion, so you should try to grasp that. All that `expl3` does is give easier control over TeX expansion (by removing the need for long `\expandafter`-chains, instead you just use argument types like `o` or `e`).