# Foreach loop with command inside Tikz matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, matrices

This question is directly related to [Foreach inside a TikZ matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22275/foreach-inside-a-tikz-matrix). But I can't expand it with a macro inside, such that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\somecommand}[1]{#1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \let\mymatrixcontent\empty
  \foreach \c in {a,b,c}{%
    \expandafter\gappto\expandafter\mymatrixcontent\expandafter{\somecommand{\c} \\}%
    % or
    % \xappto\mymatrixcontent{\expandonce{\somemacro{\c}\\}}
  }
  \matrix [matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&] {
    \mymatrixcontent
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I get the error: ERROR: Missing } inserted.

Comment: `\mymatrixcontent` expands to `\c  \\\c  \\\c  \\`.

Comment: Yes, but how do I expand \c in the foreach loop at the same time..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you add `\show\mymatrixcontent` before `\matrix`, you can see that the expansion is

```
\c  \\\c  \\\c  \\
```

which is not what you want. You have to expand `\c` before feeding it as an argument to `\somecommand`. You can do it by

```
\newcommand{\somecommand}[1]{#1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \let\mymatrixcontent\empty
  \def\gapptoaux#1{\gappto\mymatrixcontent{\somecommand{#1} \\}}
  \foreach \c in {a,b,c}{
    \expandafter\gapptoaux\expandafter{\c}
  }
  \matrix [matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&] {
    \mymatrixcontent
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have had exactly the same problem in a different context (the loop counter not being expanded in a table cell). To practice my understanding of how the expansion works I tried to fix the problematic line in the original code directly (commented in the code below) - two more `\expandafter`s do the job.

Egreg's solution looks nicer and cleaner but the crude way might be easier to understand for those like me who have only just met `\expandafter`. Hope this helps someone.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\somecommand}[1]{#1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \let\mymatrixcontent\empty
  \foreach \c in {a,b,c}{%
  %------------------------------
    % original code:
    %\expandafter\gappto\expandafter\mymatrixcontent\expandafter{\somecommand{\c} \\}%
    % changed to:
    \expandafter\gappto\expandafter\mymatrixcontent\expandafter{\expandafter\somecommand\expandafter{\c} \\}%
  %------------------------------
    % or
    % \xappto\mymatrixcontent{\expandonce{\somemacro{\c}\\}}
  }
  \matrix [matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&] {
    \mymatrixcontent
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```