# auto-pst-pdf produces a confusing error message

Tags: pstricks, standalone, auto-pst-pdf

Actually I don't want to use `auto-pst-pdf` forever. But Harish Kumar ([in his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82611/how-do-i-go-about-typesetting-a-genkou-youshi-page/82619#comment177030_82619)) requested to use it for the sake of simplicity. I tried it several decades ago and it did not work. The MWE below is the example I tried and failed.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\psset
{
    unit=\psrunit,
    polarplot,
    algebraic=true,
    plotpoints=1000,
}

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=1+1}{25}{%
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
\pscircle[linestyle=dashed](0,0){2}
\psplot[linecolor=red]{0}{TwoPi}{2+.5*cos(\i*x)}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it compiles fine if you change `standalone` to `article`; as such, perhaps add the `standalone` tag to your question

Comment: *several decades ago*... Just how old are you really? ;)

Comment: What error message do you actually get? (I got ``The program 'pdflatex' is currently not installed.`` but that's a different reason ;-) )

Comment: One workaround to use `pstricks` in `pdflatex` mode is to `\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}`. So,`auto-pst-pdf` is automatically included, thereby `pstricks` in the `standalone` document class options can be removed. Finally preamble looks like `\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}` would come first, then add ons `\usepackage{pst-plot}` and no need for `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}`. This works well for me.BTW  if you kindly post 'confusing error message' in the question it would help others.

Comment: You always should add the error message you get to the question. Also please state what exactly you want to achieve. You want to get a multi-page PDF where every page contains a single step of the animation, right?

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Yes. I want to produce a multi-page PDF where each page contains a single frame of an animation. But actually I never want to use `auto-pst-pdf`, it is just a request of Doctor Kumar in another question (forgot the link).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the documentclass `standalone` cannot work together with the `auto-pst-pdf` package and the `[pstricks]` option for `standalone`. Use

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\psset{%
    polarplot,
    algebraic,
    plotpoints=1000}

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=1+1}{25}{%
  \begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
  \pscircle[linestyle=dashed](0,0){2}
  \psplot[linecolor=red]{0}{TwoPi}{2+.5*cos(\i*x)}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

However, it makes no sense to use `standalone` *and* `auto-pst-pdf` together.

Comment: I fully agree with the last sentence.

Answer (score 5):

As Herbert already mentions in his answer, the `pstricks` option of `standalone` doesn't work with `auto-pst-pdf`. Both seem to redefine the `pspicture` environment in an incompatible way. This makes perfectly sense because both try to due basically the same thing: create one page for every `pspicture`.

In order to make both work together remove the `pstricks` option (which loads `pstricks` and sets `pspicture` as a "multi environment") and add an additional environment to let `standalone` create multiple pages:

```
\documentclass[multi=multipage]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\psset{%
    polarplot,
    algebraic,
    plotpoints=1000}

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=1+1}{25}{%
  \begin{multipage}
  \begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \pscircle[linestyle=dashed](0,0){2}
    \psplot[linecolor=red]{0}{TwoPi}{2+.5*cos(\i*x)}
  \end{pspicture}
  \end{multipage}
}
\end{document}
```

However, in this case `file.pdf` is basically identical to `file-pics.pdf` anyway and therefore you don't need to use `standalone` at all.
Simply use a document like this and use `file-pics.pdf` directly. I assume here that what you want it a multi-page PDF which contains one step at every page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\psset{%
    polarplot,
    algebraic,
    plotpoints=1000}

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=1+1}{25}{%
  \begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \pscircle[linestyle=dashed](0,0){2}
    \psplot[linecolor=red]{0}{TwoPi}{2+.5*cos(\i*x)}
  \end{pspicture}
}
\end{document}
```