# Japanese practise paper (Genkou Youshi)

Tags: templates, cjk

I'm trying to figure out a way of creating a Japanese character practice sheet. The type that I'm looking to create looks a little like the Genkou Youshi that [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82611/how-do-i-go-about-typesetting-a-genkou-youshi-page) was looking to cover. Except that a Japanese character is inserted into the topmost 4-5 boxes of a row, where the instances of the character after the first are printed in a progressively lighter shade until they have faded away completely.

Here's an example of what I'm looking to create:

[image]

Is this possible to do? If so, where should I start? I'm a bit of a beginner to TeX, but am willing to learn.

I'm currently using:

- TexMaker 3.5
- TexLive 2011
- Windows 7 (But I can move over the Debian if needed)
- [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82633/19120) from the previously mentioned question.

Comment: The Japanese character set contains a LOT of Chinese characters, too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you go. My code is a mild extension of [this answer by Paul Gaborit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82651/25356).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand\genkoyoshi[4]{%
  \def\rowopacities{#1}%
  \def\colnames{#2}%
  \def\size{#3}%
  \def\sep{#4}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\inc}{\size+\sep}
    \newcounter{col}
    \newcounter{row}
    \foreach \colname in \colnames{
      \addtocounter{col}{1}
      \setcounter{row}{0}
      \foreach \rowopacity in \rowopacities{
        \addtocounter{row}{1}
        \draw ({(\thecol-1)*\inc pt},{\therow*\size})
        rectangle ++ (\size,\size);
        \node[text=black!\rowopacity] at ({(\thecol-1)*\inc+\size*0.5 pt},{\therow*\size+\size*0.5}) {\colname};
      }
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\genkoyoshi{100,66,33,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k}{8mm}{2mm}
\end{document}
```

### Comments on the code

- The list `100,66,33,0,0,0,0,0,0,0` gives the opacity of each row -- 0 is transparent, and 100 is completely black. The length of that list gives the number of rows, hence the `0` fillers at the end.
- The list `a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k` gives the character you want in each column.
- The `8mm` is the height and width of each cell, and the `2mm` is the size of the gap between columns
- The notation `black!40` gives a colour that is 40% black and 60% white.
- Each letter is centred horizontally and vertically in its cell, which is why the `g` looks a bit high and the `d` looks a bit low. If you don't like this, change `{\colname}` on line 20 to `{\strut\colname}`.

### Result

[image]

Comment: Wow! This is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks. Wish me luck in deciphering/understanding the code

Comment: Good luck! (I added a few explanatory comments.)

Answer (score 4):

I found a suitable basis in [How to color the font of a single row in a table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26360/how-to-color-the-font-of-a-single-row-in-a-table)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{ |l|l| l| l| l| } \hline
\rowfont{\color{gray!90}}    0   & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\  \hline
\rowfont{\color{gray!80}}        1   & A & B & C & D \\ \hline
\rowfont{\color{gray!70}}        2   & A & B & C & D \\ \hline
\rowfont{\color{gray!60}}        3   & A & B & C & D \\ \hline
\rowfont{\color{gray!50}}        4   & A & B & C & D \\ \hline
\rowfont{\color{gray!40}}        5   & A & B & C & D \\ \hline
\rowfont{\color{gray!30}}        6   & A & B & C & D \\ \hline
\rowfont{\color{gray!20}}        7   & A & B & C & D \\ \hline
\rowfont{\color{gray!10}}        8   & A & B & C & D \\ \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

[image: tabu]

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer:

For right-to-left, the columns may be counted first, then the character position is as a delta of the column-total.

[image: xxx]

MWE

```
%babel
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[japanese]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}{Noto Serif CJK JP}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand\genkoyoshi[4]{%
  \def\rowopacities{#1}%
  \def\colnames{#2}%
  \def\size{#3}%
  \def\sep{#4}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\inc}{\size+\sep}
    \newcounter{ltotal}
    \foreach \n [count=\y] in \colnames{
    \setcounter{ltotal}{\y}}
    \newcounter{col}
    \newcounter{row}
    \foreach \colname in \colnames{
      \addtocounter{col}{1}
      \setcounter{row}{0}
      \foreach \rowopacity in \rowopacities{
        \addtocounter{row}{1}
        \draw ({(\thecol-1)*\inc pt},{\therow*\size})
        rectangle ++ (\size,\size);
        \node[text=black!\rowopacity] at ({(\theltotal-\thecol)*\inc+\size*0.5 pt},{\therow*\size+\size*0.5}) {\colname};
      }
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\huge
\color{blue}
\genkoyoshi{100,66,33,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}{太,陽,系,星,水,金,地,球,火,木,土}{8mm}{2mm}
\end{document}
```