# How to create Genkoyoshi horizontal template?

Tags: templates

I wanted to create a Genkō yōshi template, for typing Japanese characters.
It is just rows of squares with gaps in between.

This is what I want to do (20x20):
[image]

I have taken a look at other forms but they are all vertical instead of horizontal: [Japanese practise paper (Genkou Youshi)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115170/japanese-practise-paper-genkou-youshi)

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, Texmaker 5.0.2.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps something like this:

[image]

To do this I have used [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) to define a command `\Genkoyoashi` that accepts optional arguments to change the appearance. The images above were generated by:

```
   \Genkoyoshi
   \Genkoyoshi[color=red, columns=10, size=1.2, rows=10]
```

In general, the optional arguments are key-value pairs to set:

- `color`: the colour of the template (default: `MidnightBlue` - requires svgnames)
- `columns`: the number of columns (default: `20`)
- `rows`: the number of rows (default: `20`)
- `size`:  sets the size/scale of the boxes (default: `0.7`)

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\parindent0pt
\tikzset{
  /genkoyoshi/.cd,
    color/.initial=MidnightBlue,
    columns/.initial=20,
    rows/.initial=20,
    size/.initial=0.7
}
\newcommand\GeNkOyOsHi[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/genkoyoshi/#1}}
\newcommand\Genkoyoshi[1][]{%
  \begin{center}
    \tikzset{/genkoyoshi/.cd, #1}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\GeNkOyOsHi{size}]
      \foreach \lin in {1,...,\GeNkOyOsHi{rows}} {
          \draw[\GeNkOyOsHi{color}] (0,-\lin)--++(0.7*\GeNkOyOsHi{columns},0);
          \draw[\GeNkOyOsHi{color}] (0,-\lin-0.7)--++(0.7*\GeNkOyOsHi{columns},0);
          \foreach \bx in {0,...,\GeNkOyOsHi{columns}} {
              \draw[\GeNkOyOsHi{color}] (\bx*0.7, -\lin)--++(0,-0.7);
          }
      }
      \draw[\GeNkOyOsHi{color},thick] ([yshift=3mm]current bounding box.north west)
                      rectangle ([yshift=-3mm]current bounding box.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
}
\begin{document}

   \Genkoyoshi
   \Genkoyoshi[color=red, columns=10, size=1.2, rows=10]

\end{document}
```