# Is it possible to add node labels to some matrix column or row when building it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I want this:

[image]

which is done with

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mygridmatrix/.style={matrix of nodes, 
       row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
       nodes={draw, minimum size=1cm}, nodes in empty cells},
]

\matrix (m) [mygridmatrix]
{
&&&&&\\
&&&&&\\
&&&&&\\
&&&&&\\
&&&&&\\
&&&&&\\
};

\foreach \i [count=\xi from 0] in  {1,...,6}{
    \node also [label=above:\xi] (m-1-\i) {}; 
    \node also [label=left:\xi] (m-\i-1) {}; 
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, `\matrix` draws the grid and later on `\foreach` adds labels to first row and column nodes.

I would like to include this second part into `mygridmatrix` definition. I know I could do it with

```
\matrix (m) [mygridmatrix]
{
|[label=left:0,label=above:0]|&|[label=above:1]| ....\\
|[label=left:1]|& ...\\
...
```

but I would prefer to declare some `row 1/.style` and `column 1/.style` which automatically declare add labels related with `\pgfmatrixcurrentrow` and `\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn` (which are only known when `TiKZ` is building each node).

May be using some `late code` or `execute at end cell` but I couldn't find it.

Is it possible?

Comment: not tried ... there's a `\hypertarget` command provided by `hyperref` that allows a `\label` to be put in a location otherwise unidentified in the "usual" manner.  i don't know whether it would "survive" in such a localized environment, but it's what i would try if i needed it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you, but I need a node's `label` (in TikZ sense) and not a `\label` (in `hyperref` sense). I've changed title to make it clearer.

Comment: thanks for the clarification.  (sometimes we are misled by a too-limited vocabulary, where the same word means more than one thing.)

Comment: Is it about the drawing the grid in particular or you have other things in mind?

Comment: @percusse It's about drawing this kind of grids in particular. I was trying to simplify [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/226643/1952) to [tikz-matrix-of-objects](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226613/tikz-matrix-of-objects/226643#226643). If it's possible to add some contents to a node, why not a label? But column and row values are not remembered once used.

Answer (score 4):

With some help from [Zarko](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386552/1952) and some from [percusse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175803/1952) I've managed to define several `.styles` which can be used to add labels to nodes on top row and left column on a `matrix` more or less automatically.

The `style` proposed by [Zarko](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386552/1952) can be easily applied to a row or column, but it doesn't work for corner cells where a left and top label have to be applied. As a workaround solution I've defined some `.list` styles which are applied to all except first elements of top row or left column in a `matrix`.

Another consideration has been necessary to distinguish between `empty` and `non empty` cells.

I'm still not very satisfied with the code, so if you can improve, just let me know or add an answer with better solutions.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [
    toplabel/.style={
        row 1 column #1/.style={%
            execute at begin cell={%
                |[label=\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn]|},
            execute at empty cell={%
                \node[label=\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn]{};}
        }
    },
    leftlabel/.style={
        row #1 column 1/.style={%
            execute at begin cell={%
                |[label=left:\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow]|},
            execute at empty cell={%
                \node[label=left:\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow]{};}
        }
    },
    topleft/.style={
        row 1 column 1/.style={%
            execute at begin cell={%
                |[label=\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn,
                    label=left:\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow]|},
            execute at empty cell={%
                \node[label=left:\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow,
                    label=\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn]{};}
        }
    }
]
\matrix (A) [
    matrix of nodes, 
    nodes in empty cells,
    nodes={draw, minimum size=1cm, anchor=center},
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    topleft,
    toplabel/.list={2,...,6},
    leftlabel/.list={2,...,6}
]
{A&A& &A&A& \\  
  &A&A&A&A&A\\
 A&A& & &A&A\\
  &A&A&A& &A\\
 A&A&A&A&A&A\\
 A& & & & & \\};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1). good trick with lists, but i need more time to figured out their use.

Answer (score 2):

If you accept to not use the first row and column, you can use the styles `row 1`, `column 1` and `row 1 column 1` to do the following :

```
\documentclass[border=7mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  mygridmatrix/.style={matrix of nodes,
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={draw, minimum size=1cm,anchor=center},
    nodes in empty cells},
  row 1/.append style={nodes={draw=none,node contents=\pgfmathparse{int(\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn-2)}\pgfmathresult}},
  column 1/.append style={nodes={draw=none,node contents=\pgfmathparse{int(\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-2)}\pgfmathresult}},
  row 1 column 1/.append style={nodes={node contents=}},
]

\matrix (m) [mygridmatrix]
{
&&&&&\\
&&&&&\\
&&&&&\\
&&&&&\\
&&&&&\\
&&&&&\\
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice trick. +1.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that the original question was about a particular issue with styles in Ti*k*Z and on how to deal with a `matrix` grid and numbers outside of it. But as soon as I view your main issue with the matrix grid and numbers of rows and columns, it brings to mind a package that is used, however, for more playful purposes: [LogicPuzzle package](https://ctan.org/pkg/logicpuzzle?lang=en).

It is easy to use the ***skyline*** puzzle for making rectangular grids with empty cells and/or with numbers/letters in them, and the rows and columns can be numbered in each side of the rectangle, with options:

```
\skylineL{...} % For left
\skylineT{...} % For top
\skylineR{...} % For right
\skylineB{...} % For bottom
```

Also, there are another features like: coloring of cells, highlighting the contour of some cells, among others. (See [my answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/408008/125434) as an example.)
So if you consider this answer does not meet your spectations or helps you in some way, take it as a *just for fun* answer.

### Output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}    
\usepackage{logicpuzzle}

\begin{document}

\begin{skyline}[rows=6, columns=6]
    \skylineL{6,5,4,3,2,1}
    \skylineT{1,2,3,4,5,6}
    \setrow{6}{A,A,{},A,A,{}}
    \setrow{5}{{},A,A,A,A,A}
    \setrow{4}{A,A,{},{},A,A}
    \setrow{3}{{},A,A,A,{},A}
    \setrow{2}{A,A,A,A,A,A}
    \setrow{1}{A,{},{},{},{},{}}
\end{skyline}

\end{document}
```