# Automated matrix padding in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, foreach, tikz-matrix

I encounter an error with the following code :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart, fit,backgrounds,calc}


\begin{document}

\node[matrix, column sep=1cm,] (postes){%
\foreach\x in{1,...,5}{%
\node{poste};&
}
\node{poste};\\
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In that case, I use a matrix in order to obtain a multi-column matrix with the `foreach` command but it seems that it is inappropriate.
I was wondering if some simple solution for padding automatically a matrix in tikz existed.

Comment: Your MWE is not complete. In it are missed used TikZ libraries, definition for `\pposte` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a completely automatic solution like the one proposed in [Tikz foreach inside matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60394/tikz-foreach-inside-matrix/60400#60400) but `node contents` and `nodes in empty cells` options can help to provide a semiautomatic solution.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix (m) [draw, matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells, 
       nodes={draw, 
         node contents={$A_{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}$}}, 
       row sep=2mm, column sep=1mm]
{
&&&&&\\
&&&&&\\
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile during wait on solution for automatic padding of matrix see if the next solution is work for you:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 3mm,
    every node/.style = {draw, inner sep=1mm},
                    ]
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,5}
    \node (n\i) at (\i,0) {$A_{1\i}$};
\node[fit=(n1) (n5)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Obtained picture is:

[image]