# tikz square box array side by side alignment

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wish to draw square box array side by side, but my code below still has gap between square box. My math is wrong?

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\def\m{25pt}
\tiny\begin{tikzpicture}[
    square/.style={draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4,minimum size=\m,fill=gray!50},
    outer sep=0,inner sep=0]
    \def\w{6}
    \def\h{4}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\uw{int(\w/2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\uh{int(\h/2)}
    %Y
  \foreach \x in {1,...,\w}
    \foreach \y in {1,...,\h}
       {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{(\y-1) * \w + \x}
       \node [square]  (Y\x,\y) at (\x*\m,-\y*\m) {Y\label};
       }
    %U
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\uw}
    \foreach \y in {1,...,\uh}
       {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{(\y-1) * \uw + \x}
       \node [square,fill=blue!50]  (U\x,\y) at (\x*\m,-\y*\m- \h*\m) {U\label};
       }
       %V
       \foreach \x in {1,...,\uw}
    \foreach \y in {1,...,\uh}
       {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{(\y-1) * \uw + \x}
       \node [square,fill=yellow!50]  (V\x,\y) at (\x*\m,-\y*\m - \h*\m-\uh*\m) {V\label};
       }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: If you set `minimum width=35pt` this will fix your MWE, but if you subsequently  change `\m` then you need to change this adjustment...so this is a work-around rather than a fix.

Comment: Is there special reason that for simple rectangle you use `regular polygon` shape? If you use `rectangle`, you will obtain what you wish ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Source of your problem is in definition of regular polygons:

> If the node is enlarged to any specified minimum size, this is
>   interpreted as the diameter of the circumcircle, that is, the circle
>   that passes through all the corners of the polygon border.

(TikZ  & PGF manual, pp. 699)

With other words, with `\m` you define diagonals of rectangles not length of borders. Since the coordinates are determined with length of diagonals, your rectangles has gaps with length (diagonal length) - (border length). Ratio between this two lengths is `\square{2}`.

The possible cure:

- recalculate coordinates of rectangles
- instead regular polygons use simple rectangle

**Edit:**
in the first case the solution is:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
square/.style = {draw, rectangle, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=4, 
                 minimum size=\m, outer sep=0, inner sep=0,
                 fill=gray!50, font=\tiny,
                 },
                        ]
\def\m{25pt}
\def\w{6}
\def\h{4}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\uw{int(\w/2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\uh{int(\h/2)}
    %Y
  \foreach \x in {1,...,\w}
    \foreach \y in {1,...,\h}
       {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{(\y-1) * \w + \x}
       \node [square]  (Y\x,\y) at (\x*\m/1.414,-\y*\m/1.414) {Y\label};
       }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the second case the MWE (for the first part of your rectangle arrays) is simpler:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
square/.style = {draw, rectangle, %regular polygon, regular polygon sides=4, 
                 minimum size=\m, outer sep=0, inner sep=0,
                 fill=gray!50, font=\tiny,
                 },
                        ]
\def\m{25pt}
\def\w{6}
\def\h{4}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\uw{int(\w/2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\uh{int(\h/2)}
    %Y
  \foreach \x in {1,...,\w}
    \foreach \y in {1,...,\h}
       {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{(\y-1) * \w + \x}
       \node [square]  (Y\x,\y) at (\x*\m,-\y*\m) {Y\label};
       }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Both examples gives similar result:

[image]

**Note:** 
In the second solution the rectangles in array are bigger than in the first case!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to draw an array you can use a `matrix of nodes`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (Y) [matrix of nodes, nodes={draw, anchor=center, minimum size=25pt, outer sep=0pt, fill=gray!30},
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth]{
    Y1 & Y2 & Y3 & Y4 & Y5 & Y6\\
    Y7 & Y8 & Y9 & Y10 & Y11 & Y12\\
    Y13 & Y14 & Y15 & Y16 & Y17 & Y18\\
    Y19 & Y20 & Y21 &|[fill=green!30, text=red]| Y22 & Y23 & Y24\\
    Y25 & Y26 & Y27 & Y28 & Y29 & Y30\\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update: automatic matrix contents**

It seems that [is not possible to expand a `\foreach` construction](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22276/1952) but it's possible to build the matrix contents into a macro and use it later. I don't understand Martin's code and I don't understand [percusse's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60400/1952) to [Tikz foreach inside matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60394/tikz-foreach-inside-matrix) 
which expands Martin's solution to a 2D matrix. But I could transform it to a command with two parameters (matrix width and height).

```
\content{width}{height}
```

This command, which must be executed before `matrix` declaration, defines the macro `\mymatrixcontent` which will be used as `matrix` content.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\content}[2]{%
    \let\mymatrixcontent\empty
    \foreach \j in {1,...,#2}{
        \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \myindex using {int((\j-1)*#1+\i)}] in {1,...,#1}{%
            \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
                \noexpand\gappto\noexpand\mymatrixcontent{Y\myindex\&}}\x
            }%
        \gappto\mymatrixcontent{\\}%
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\content{3}{5}
\matrix (Y) [ampersand replacement = \&,
                matrix of nodes,  
                nodes={draw, anchor=center, minimum size=25pt, 
                    outer sep=0pt, fill=gray!30},
               column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
               row sep=-\pgflinewidth]{
    \mymatrixcontent
    };

\content{4}{3}
\matrix (Z) [right = of Y, ampersand replacement = \&,
                matrix of nodes,  
                draw, fill=blue!30,
                nodes={draw, anchor=center, minimum size=25pt, 
                    outer sep=0pt, fill=red!30},
               column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
               row sep=-\pgflinewidth]{
    \mymatrixcontent
    };

\content{2}{2}
\matrix (W) [right = of Z, ampersand replacement = \&,
                matrix of nodes,  
                nodes={draw, anchor=center, minimum size=25pt, 
                    outer sep=0pt, fill=blue!30},
               column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
               row sep=-\pgflinewidth]{
    \mymatrixcontent
    };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good, is it possible to use \w and \h as variable for matrix size?

Comment: @lucky1928    Do you mean defining the array contents programatically? What's the contents of each square?

Comment: I mean the dimension such as 6x4 or 8x6. I wish to just change the \w and \h definition to get different matrix.

Comment: @lucky1928 Try with updated answer. I think it does what you want.