# Hoffmansingleton graph I would like to learn how to draw this graph in latex -

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, tikz-node

I need ideas on how to draw the Hoffman Singleton graph in LaTeX.

Comment: The [question you already asked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/559199/i-need-assistance-with-how-to-draw-the-hoffman-singleton-graph-in-latex) on the subject was closed because it lacks details. Indeed, posting an image and asking 'how to draw this' is not a reasonable thing to ask on this website, as is the present question. Please, provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I need assistance with how to draw the Hoffman Singleton graph in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/559199/i-need-assistance-with-how-to-draw-the-hoffman-singleton-graph-in-latex)

Answer (score 4):

A `sagetex` solution is easy because [Sage knows the Hoffman Singleton graph](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph_generators.html):

```
\documentclass[border={2mm 2mm 8mm 8mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage{sagetex,xcolor,tikz,tkz-graph,tkz-berge}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
g = graphs.HoffmanSingletonGraph()
g.set_pos(g.layout_circular())
g.set_latex_options(graphic_size=(20,20))
\end{sagesilent}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 10mm and 10mm]
\tikzset{EdgeStyle/.append style = {color = blue!60, line width=1pt}}
\sage{g}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Running in Cocalc this gives:
[image]

Sage is not part of the LaTeX distribution. The easiest way to access is with a [free Cocalc account](https://cocalc.com/). Search this site for `sagetex` for more information. There is more explanation in my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/552241/how-to-automatically-ask-tikz-to-produce-the-coordinates-and-plot-the-graph-from/552287#552287).

Answer (score 2):

In the future, please try to provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) presenting a technical issue that you encountered trying to draw a given figure.
Indeed, as stated in my comment, questions asking "How do I draw this?" are not reasonable questions to ask on this website.
If you have difficulties with TikZ, there are [a lot of resources online](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15779/materials-for-learning-tikz) to help you.

Since I do not know how to use the `graph` library of TikZ, here is an example with `foreach` loops to draw and link the elements.
The drawing is based on the image provided in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/559199/i-need-assistance-with-how-to-draw-the-hoffman-singleton-graph-in-latex?noredirect=1&lq=1).

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\xoffset}{5cm}
\newcommand{\yoffset}{6cm}
\newcommand{\pentaoffset}{1.5}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
        \foreach \x in {0,1}{
            \foreach \y in {0,1,2,3,4}{
                \foreach \z in {0,1,2,3,4}{
                    \coordinate (\x\y\z) at ($({\y*\xoffset}, {-\x*\yoffset}) + ({\z*72+90}:\pentaoffset)$);
                }
            }
        }
    
        \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4}{
            \draw (0\x0) -- (0\x1) -- (0\x2) -- (0\x3) -- (0\x4) -- (0\x0);
            \draw (1\x0) -- (1\x2) -- (1\x4) -- (1\x1) -- (1\x3) -- (1\x0);
            \draw (0\x0) -- (0\x1) -- (0\x2) -- (0\x3) -- (0\x4) -- (0\x0);
            \foreach \y in {0,1,2,3,4}{
                \foreach \z in {0,1,2,3,4}{
                    \draw (0\x\z) -- (1\y\z);
                }
            }
        }
    
        \foreach \y in {0,1,2,3,4}{
            \foreach \z in {0,1,2,3,4}{
                \node[%
                    circle,
                    draw,
                    fill = white,
                    minimum size = 1cm
                ] at (0\y\z) {\y,\z};
            }
        }
    
        \foreach \y in {0,1,2,3,4}{
            \foreach \z in {0,1,2,3,4}{
                \node[%
                    circle,
                    draw,
                    fill = white,
                    minimum size = 1cm
                ] at (1\y\z) {{\y}x,\z};
            }
        }
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

which yields:

[image]

The distances in the preamble can be modified to suit the user's needs.