# Create 2-d matrix with foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

This example is copied from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22275/foreach-inside-a-tikz-matrix) SO. but I wish to create a two dimension matrix with foreach loop\documentclass{standalone}

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \let\desc\empty
    \foreach \x/\y in {a/b,b/c,c/d}{%
        \xappto\desc{\expandonce{\x \\}}
        %\xappto\desc{\expandonce{\x & \y \\}}
    }
    \matrix [matrix of nodes] {
        \desc
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But if I open the commented line instead the one dimension version, compile will failure!

How should I modify this example to support 2-d matrix create with foreach loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am more or less copying [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60400) here. An important point is to use `ampersand replacement`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \let\desc\empty
    \foreach \x/\y in {a/b,b/c,c/d}{%
       \xappto\desc{\x \& \y\\}%     
      }%

    \matrix [matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&] {
        \desc
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: I hope this question is about using `\foreach` in a matrix. If you just want to have the output, you can of course do

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes]{a&b\\ c&d\\ e&f\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which is as short as [Steven's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/530606/194703) but has the additional possibility of adding all sorts of pgf keys to obtain something like

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,column sep=0pt,row sep=0pt,
cells={nodes={top color=blue,bottom color=red,text=white,
    minimum size=1.8em,anchor=center}}]{a&b\\ c&d\\ e&f\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As long as neither the stacking TAB nor EOL is a `/` slash character, a simple TABstack can do this directly.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\begin{document}
\setstackTAB{?}%
\setstackEOL{,}%
\setstacktabbedgap{1ex}%
\Matrixstack{a?b,b?c,c?d}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want it in text, rather than math, mode, simply change the `\Matrixstack{a?b,b?c,c?d}` to `\tabbedCenterstack{a?b,b?c,c?d}`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks,never know this package before! Is it possible to address elements? for example, draw a curve line from 1-2 to 3-2?

Comment: @lucky1928 I'm sorry, `tabstackengine` is not like `tikz` in it graphical capabilities, so if your goal is to create a matrix and then overlay nodal "activity" upon it, it would be best to stick with `tikz`.