# Using pgffor's \foreach to place graphics into a tabular

Tags: tables, graphics, foreach

I want to arrange EPS graphics (included via `\includegraphics`) in a `tabular` using `\foreach`. Currently this is done without any loops like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{*5{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.15\textwidth}}}
    $X_{40}$ & $X_{60}$ & $X_{80}$ & $X_{120}$ & $X_{160}$ \\

    \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{./testrun/testvar_type_X_40.eps}
    & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{./testrun/testvar_type_X_60.eps}
    & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{./testrun/testvar_type_X_80.eps}
    & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{./testrun/testvar_type_X_140.eps}
    & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{./testrun/testvar_type_X_160.eps} \\

    \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{./testrun/testvar_type_Xest_40.eps}
    & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{./testrun/testvar_type_Xest_60.eps}
    & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{./testrun/testvar_type_Xest_80.eps}
    & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{./testrun/testvar_type_Xest_140.eps}
    & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{./testrun/testvar_type_Xest_160.eps} \\
\end{tabular}
```

As you can see, the second and third row have some redundancy. Additionally in each row all columns differ only in the numbers 40, 60, 80, 140, 160. So my idea is, to use at least a `\foreach` in each row to put the numbers in there.

My attempt doing so arose from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22276. However, using `\includegraphics` in there does not seem to work (`Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }`). This is the code used:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\let\tabularContent\empty

\newcommand{\plotChannels}{
    \foreach \channel in {40,60,80,120,160}{
        \begingroup\edef\x{
            \endgroup\noexpand\gappto\noexpand\tabularContent{
                & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{./testrun/testvar_type_X_\channel.eps}
            }
        }\x
    }
    \gappto\tabularContent{\\}
}

\plotChannels


\begin{tabular}{*6{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.15\textwidth}}}
    $X_{40}$ & $X_{60}$ & $X_{80}$ & $X_{120}$ & $X_{160}$ \\

    \tabularContent

    & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{./testrun/testvar_type_Xest_40.eps}
    & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{./testrun/testvar_type_Xest_60.eps}
    & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{./testrun/testvar_type_Xest_80.eps}
    & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{./testrun/testvar_type_Xest_140.eps}
    & \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{./testrun/testvar_type_Xest_160.eps} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: you are missing (at least) a \noexpand before \includegraphics

Comment: Thanks for your useful comments. I added the MWE. Putting \noexpand before \includegraphics solves the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a `\noexpand` before `\includegraphics`

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,array,ragged2e}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\newtoks\tabtoks
\newcommand\addtabtoks[1]{\tabtoks\expandafter{\the\tabtoks#1}}
\newcommand*\printtabtoks{\the\tabtoks}

\begin{document}
\tabtoks{}
\addtabtoks{\tabular{*5{>{\Centering}m{.15\textwidth}}@{}l@{}}}
\addtabtoks{$X_{40}$ & $X_{60}$ & $X_{80}$ & $X_{120}$ & $X_{160}$ \\ }
\foreach\channel in {40,60,80,120,160}{% 
  \global\addtabtoks{\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{./testrun/testvar_type_X_\channel} &}}
\addtabtoks{\endtabular}
\printtabtoks

\end{document}
```

[image]