# Expand Tikz matrix with foreach statement?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, tikz-matrix

I am playing with Tikz matrices and would like to use the foreach statement to "expand a matrix". More precisely, I wonder if I can use a foreach statement such as:

```
\n in {Alice (the genious), Bob, Smith, Gordon}{ code }
```

together with the tikz matrix environment in order to achieve and end result that looks like

[image]

The **manual** code to achieve the above output is:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[anchor=west]

\matrix[matrix of nodes]
{
    ID nr                   & Status    & Volume    \\
    1.2345                  & Blue      & 2.2       \\
    Creator                 & Last touch& Date      \\
    {Alice (the genious)}   & Jason     & 20190129  \\
    {Bob}                   &           &           \\
    {Smith}                 &           &           \\
    {Gordon}                &           &           \\
    {Theme:}                &           &           \\
    {Let's use tikz }       &           &           \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: @tjoflong It is very vague/unclear on what you want to achieve per se. Could not grasp it from your question. Would you explain us better?

Comment: I have updated the question. Hopefully it is now clear what I want to do.

Comment: Yes, you can create the rows with a `\foreach` loop, but it is not absolutely straightforward. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/165126/121799) and the many linked posts for how that works. I would like to argue that in this case it may not be worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks for the response — that looks like hard work! I managed to achieve the wanted result by a little cheating... I made a few tikz matrices and used "matrix anchor" to align them correctly. One of the matrices was made using a foreach statement as pointed out [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22275/foreach-inside-a-tikz-matrix?rq=1).