# TikZ: How to create a list with calculated entries for a style

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys, pgfmath, tikz-matrix, pgfmathparse

I have a TikZ-matrix. And I want to highlight the rows 
`1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28,... =n*(n+1)/2`

For small examples, I could do it this way:

```
highlight/.style={  row #1/.style={....}   },
highlight/.list={1,3,6,10,15}
```

But my question is: Think about a quite bigger number of rows (say 1000) - *how can I automate that by using the calculation "`n*(n+1)/2`"?*

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
highlight/.style={  row #1/.style={nodes={fill=pink}}   },
]
\matrix[matrix of nodes,
highlight/.list={1,3,6,10,15}
](m){
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
4 \\
5 \\
6 \\
7 \\
8 \\
9 \\
10  \\
11 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn\my_calculate:n #1
  { , \int_eval:n{#1*(#1+1)/2} }

\newcommand\createlist[1]{
  \int_step_function:nnN{1}{#1}\my_calculate:n
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  highlight/.style={row #1/.style={nodes={fill=pink}}},
]
  \matrix[matrix of nodes,
    highlight/.list/.expanded={\createlist{5}}
  ] (m) {
    1 \\
    2 \\
    3 \\
    4 \\
    5 \\
    6 \\
    7 \\
    8 \\
    9 \\
    10 \\
    11 \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe a pgffor loop could be added for the matrix.

Comment: @projetmbc That would be nice, but this is not trivial - as far I know. You can address it in a question "How to create a TikZ matrix with a loop", if you want.

Comment: @cis Have you try to play with this [https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22276/6880](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22276/6880) ?

Comment: @projetmbc  Ah, interesting. In the case here, I needed something  that I can use a listwise applied style, so the matrix was coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's just integer calculations that hopefully don't surpass 2³¹−1 you can use `\int_eval:n`, `\inteval` (which is a front-end version of int_eval) or `\pgfinteval` (which is a clone of the previous) inside the key specification:

```
highlight/.style={
  row \inteval{#1*(#1+1)/2}/.append style={nodes={fill=pink}}}
```

If you don't want to alter the `highlight` key you can use a forwarder, of course:

```
highlight/.style={row #1/.append style={nodes={fill=pink}}},
highlight'/.style={highlight=\pgfinteval{#1*(#1+1)/2}}
```

It would also be possible to create something like

```
highlight/.list wrap={1, ..., 1000}{\inteval{#1*(#1+1)/2}}`
```

if the previous suggestion are not nice enough.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{
  create column/.style={
    matrix content/.initial=,
    /utils/temp/.style={
      matrix content/.append={##1\pgfmatrixendrow}},
    /utils/temp/.list={#1},
    node contents=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix content}}}
\begin{document}
\tikz[
  highlight/.style={
    row \inteval{#1*(#1+1)/2}/.append style={nodes={fill=pink}}}]
\matrix (m) [
  matrix of nodes,
  highlight/.list={1, ..., 1000},
  create column={1, ..., 1000}];

\tikz[
  highlight/.style={row #1/.append style={nodes={fill=pink}}},
  highlight'/.style={highlight=\pgfinteval{#1*(#1+1)/2}}]
\matrix (m) [
  matrix of nodes,
  highlight'/.list={1, ..., 1000},
  create column={1, ..., 1000}];
\end{document}
```